# Blazor Web Assembly Redirecting to Controller

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I am using Blazor Web Assembly using ASP.NET WebHosting. So 2 projects Client and Server. They launch https://localhost:4000

Looking at the example FetchData which calls an API for WeatherForecasts and the address is https://localhost:4000/WeatherForecasts

I am creating a integration with a third party (xero is my example) so I have a controller called XeroAuthController in the Server project app. The Action "Connect" sends a URL to redirect to. If I type https://localhost:4000/XeroAuth/Connect. I get the page not found.

I have added the attribute [Route("[controller]")] to the XeroAuthController

Is there something I need to do to add the route into the client sides known routes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below.

Create Service Layer in you client project.

Add - Interface and Implementation class

Interface -

```
public interface IXeroAuth
{
  Task XeroConnect(); //you can pass  parameter or object if required here
}
```

Implementation -

```
public class XeroAuth : IXeroAuth
{
  private readonly IHttpService httpService;
  private string url = "api/XeroAuth"; // XeroAuth is Controller name

  public XeroAuth(IHttpService httpService)
  {
        this.httpService = httpService;
  }

  public async Task XeroConnect()
    {
        // POST OR GET etc.. it depends how your controller is defined
        var response = await httpService.Post(url); 

        //Handle response here
    }
}
```

Controller Sample

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class XeroAuth: ControllerBase
{
  //Your code here which will handle connect request..
}
```

Hope this helps.